# Android Auto Complete Text View

Tags: android, sqlite, autocomplete

Good day! I am working with an auto complete text view in android. The idea is to get two columns from sqlite (in my case pid, pname and size) and with the given constraints the data from the database will be shown (pid, pname, and size). Whenever I test it, it is only the pname that shows.

public Cursor getMatchingProduct(String constraint) throws SQLException {

```
    String queryString =
            "SELECT _pid `_id`, pname, size FROM " + dbase.TABLE1;

    if (constraint != null) {
        constraint = constraint.trim() + "%";
        queryString += " WHERE pname LIKE ?";
    }
    String params[] = { constraint };

    if (constraint == null) {
        params = null;
    }
    try {
        db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(queryString, params);
        if (cursor != null) {
            ((Activity) this.context).startManagingCursor(cursor);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            return cursor;
        }
    }
    catch (SQLException e) {

        throw e;
    }
    db.close();
    return null;
}
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would expect the queryString to be just

```
String queryString = "SELECT _pid, pname, size FROM " + dbase.TABLE1;
```

unless your table name is actually pid and not _pid, then it would be

```
 String queryString = "SELECT pid, pname, size FROM " + dbase.TABLE1;
```